# Active Directory Force Logoff After 8 Hours

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

We are a 24/7 company and we have an active directory network of approximately 80 workstations.  Our employees do not seem to be logging off when they leave their shift and others are using their accounts.  How can I make it so if John Doe's user account is logged in for 8 hours, it will automatically logout?

Shifts can occur at any time for any user, so I can't do it by a set time period either. :(

Comment: Is what happens to unsaved work important?

Comment: It would be nice to give them a warning, but it's not necessary.

Comment: have you set any Group policy (Script (logon/logoff)) to achieve this task?

Comment: No, I don't know how.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Group Policy Preferences (GPP) for this. GPP would allow you to set a number of conditions to determine for whom the task is created (machine MAC address, security group membership, OU the user or computer is in, etc.).

You would create a scheduled task to run as the user. This task would run

```
shutdown.exe /l /f
```

For the trigger on the scheduled task, you would set the task to run at log on, with a delay of 8 hours.

[image]

Getting Started Guide for Group Policy Preferences: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

batch login script:

- call vbs script

vbs script:

Wscript.Sleep(28800000)
SET wshell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wshell.exec("shutdown.exe -L -F")

Comment: How would I install this on the domain?  I tried to add it via: User Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Scripts/Logon, Scripts Tab, saved as .vbs, but it doesn't do anything on the workstation.

Comment: Did you test it locally? How do you start vbs script?

Comment: I put it on a workstation and double clicked it and it performed as expected.  But when I added it to scripts as a .vbs, it didn't load.

Comment: Do you start vbs script thru batch as I told you?

Comment: Can I just rename it as .bat or do I have to do more?

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to do more. More more. Start reading and learing:   https://vmin.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/logon-scripts-on-a-windows-server/   http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/common/Logon-Scripts-Pure-Mixed-Active-Directory-Environments.html